# Converting Array to object without any key or single key

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I just  want to  create an object which contains all the values of an array on a sigle key .

```
arr1 = [{ x: 12, y:13},{ x1: 14, y2:15}];
arr2 = [{ xx: 18, yy:18},{ xx1: 17, yy2:16}];

// result = { finalObj :[{ x: 12, y:13},{ x1: 14, y2:15}],[{ xx: 18, yy:18},{ xx1: 17, yy2:16}]}
```

Although  i can get final array by :

```
const finalArr = arr1.concat(arr2);
```

But how to get the end result .
Thanks in advance .

Comment: so `{ finalObj : arr1.concat(arr2) }`

Comment: Just use JSON serialisation/deserialisation. create an object with the key and having a value of an empty array.. add things to the array and then use JSON.. http://www.tutorialspark.com/javascript/JavaScript_JSON_Parsing_Serialization.php

Comment: the object in your exemple is not correct, it should be either `{ finalObj :[{ x: 12, y:13},{ x1: 14, y2:15}, { xx: 18, yy:18},{ xx1: 17, yy2:16}]}` either `{ finalObj :[[{ x: 12, y:13},{ x1: 14, y2:15}],[{ xx: 18, yy:18},{ xx1: 17, yy2:16}]]}`

Comment: @JGFMK [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)? Where did you find [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) (or a reference to it) in the question? o.O

Comment: @Andreas `[{ x: 12, y:13},{ x1: 14, y2:15}]`; is as JSON array with two JSON objects. Objects are of the form `{}` ... arrays `[]`...

Comment: @JGFMK [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: @Andreas - all you need to know are parse/stringify... and you can get to what you need that way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concat two arrays

```
{ finalObj: [...arr1, ...arr2] }
```